# Webform Integration - Permission level for viewing the civicrm contact name column

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

Just curious if anyone using Drupal and the Webform integration has come across this:

When viewing results as an admin, I can see clickable links to the Civi individual who filled out the form - it's great! But I noticed that not all my users can see data in that column (they see the column it's just empty.)

If you click the view button for a submission, they can see (and click) the Civi Individual - but that same info does not show up on the list of completed submissions.

After some testing, I found that you have to give user the permission set "Edit All Webform Submissions" which is a little awkward. I just want this user set to VIEW the name of the person who completed the form and be able to click right over to civi (without having to open each survey).

Drupal 7.41 Webforms Civi 7.x.4.11

Any advice on how to accomplish this? Does it perhaps not behave this way in a future version?

Comment: Interested in your workflow here. A user fills in a webform, then you want them to be able to ....?

Comment: Ah, sorry the word user is misleading there. A front end 'user' is filling the form out using a checksum. A set of employees (assigned to a role in drupal) need to be able to see the results of the survey. But not be able to edit the results of the survey, much less any other surveys on the site.

Comment: How about give them a View showing exactly what you want them to see, rather than sending them to the results?

Comment: That's a definite option (as it will also allow the download of a csv) was just wondering if the permission issue had come up for anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

The [permissions per webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_per_webform) module overrides the webform permissions. When this module is installed and enabled, there will be a tab on the form settings called 'Permission settings' for every webform node. With this you can control the results tab on each webform by role. You can use only the Access webform results and Edit webform results.

Please test this module before using on production